# Testing jdbc queries and prepared statements

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc

I have a class where i have created connection to h2 database using old jdbc method of writing url and getting connection , and I am creating a table in the database, this is table is not a java object so i am running out of clever ways to write a test for my methods 
This one of the methods

```
//above would be the url and driver connection
```

//also i created a table app_user
    public void addUser(Connection connection,
                            String login, String password,
                            String description) throws SQLException {

```
        System.out.println(String.format("Add user : %s", login));

        String newUSer = "INSERT INTO app_user(login, password, description) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(newUSer)) {

            preparedStatement.setString(1, login);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, description);

            // returns number of changed column
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
    }
```

And my test method looks like this , is there any way to make it less tidious and more simple , i tried to to mocking with mockito but my app_user table is not an object of a class App_user , so i wrote this

```
@Test
    public void addUser() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {


        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "sa", "")) {

            String createTable =
                    "CREATE TABLE app_user(" +
                            "user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                            "login VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ," +
                            "password VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ," +
                            "description VARCHAR (255) NULL," +
                            "PRIMARY KEY (user_id))";

            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                statement.executeUpdate(createTable);
                Assert.assertNotNull(statement);
            }

            String addUser = "INSERT INTO app_user(login, password, description) VALUES (1234,'valentine','javaMan')";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(addUser);
            int rowAffected = statement.executeUpdate();

            Assert.assertNotNull(rowAffected);
            Assert.assertEquals(rowAffected,1);
        }
```

But i dont like the fact that in my test i had create connection again, Note-for some reason i cant use objects as table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as creating JDBC connections is concerned, I think there's an elegant way to minimize your efforts.
Instead of creating a connection every time, I'd recommend writing a Singleton Class representing JDBC connection. This would avoid some of the work that you would be doing over and again.

Something along the lines of following code. (Skipping exceptions and further details)

```
class Database{
    Connection jdbc;
    //Can store username, url , password etc as private fields here
    private Database(){
        if(jdbc == null){
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            jdbc = DriverManager.getConnection("URL", "sa", "");
        }
    }
    Connection getConnection(){
        if(jdbc == null){
            this();
        }
        return jdbc;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show a how it should look, i know a singleton class but have never used such pattern @Ashutosh thanks

Comment: @valik I've added code snippets for reference, hope it helps.

Comment: this singleton class should be in my test class @Ashutosh or a seperate class

Comment: You can place this singleton class in a separate class or package and use it's methods when needed. That's the point. Also, it'd be nice if you could upvote an answer if it's helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to access the method , Here is what i tried, Database db = Database.getInstance(); also tried using  "new" , then added an instantiation of the class inside the db class itself but nothing  @Ashutosh

Comment: Did you try making the Database class public?

Comment: yes i did and it cant call getInstance so i added  public static Database getInstance( ) {
      return database;
   } but doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165347/discussion-between-ashutosh-and-valik).

Answer (score 1):

Personally the best method I've found is creating a static class `TestUtils` and add, among the others, a static method to open and query db, and another method to close connection. The connection itself is a member of the class. SQL query to search for is a string parameter, and the ResultSet is a value to be returned.

Below there is the class.

```
public class TestUtils {
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
    private static ResultSet rs;

    public static ResultSet readDB(String sql) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        //lettura ladder da db insieme a configs
        // JDBC driver name and database URL
        final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sportservicelive";

        //  Database credentials
        final String USER = "root";
        final String PASS = "root";

        //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //STEP 3: Open a connection

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        //STEP 4: Execute a query

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        return rs;
    }

    public static void closeDB() throws SQLException {
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
        rs.close();
    }
    [...]
}
```

Of course it contains various other methods useful for unit testing.